# Transpose only certain data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data looks like this:

```
Company Year         Total   Comment                 
Comp A  01-01-2000   5,000   Checked
Comp A  01-01-2001   6,000   Checked
Comp B  05-05-2007   3,000   Not checked completely
Comp B  05-05-2008   4,000   Checked
Comp C  18-01-2003   1,500   Not checked completely
Comp C  18-01-2002   3,500   Not checked completely
```

I've been asked to transpose certain data, but I do not believe this can be done using SQL (Server) so that it looks like this:

```
Company     Base Date   Base Date-1   Comment Base Date      Comment Base Date-1
Comp A      01-01-2001  01-01-2000    Checked                Checked
Comp B      05-05-2008  05-05-2007    Checked                Not completely checked
Comp C      18-01-2003  18-01-2002    Not completely checked Not completely checked
```

I have never built anything like this. If I would then maybe Excel is a better alternative? How should I tackle this?

Is it possible using SELECT MAX(Base Date) and MIN(Base Date)? And how would I then tackle the strings like that..

Comment: what is the logic here?

Comment: That is just how they want it..And it's based on certain information. So imagine a company and then 2 years they have checked certain things. And they want that on just one line, instead of multiple lines

Comment: to make this happen, you need an additional field that tells you how to group the records.

Comment: say you have 10 years worth of data, does each date have to be shown with the previous year's date and the corresponding comment?

Comment: How would a groupby work for this situation?

Comment: So this needs to be done for 5,000 companies or so

Comment: Will each company always have exactly two records? If not, what do you want to show when the number of records is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assign a row number to each record partitioned by company ordered by year desc though an analytical function in a common table expression... then use a left self join... on the row number + 1 and company.

This assumes you only want 1 record per company using the 2 most recent years. and if only 1 record exists for a company null values are acceptable for the second year.  If not we can change the left join to an inner and eliminate both records...

We use a common table expression (though a inline view would work as well) to assign a row number to each record.  That value is then made available in our self join so we don't have to worry about different dates and max values.  We then use our RowNumber (RN) and company to join the 2 desired records together.  To save on some performance we limit 1 table to RN 1 and the second table to RN 2.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, Row_Number() over (Partition by Company Order by Year Desc) RN FROM TABLE)

SELECT A.Company
     , A.Year as Base_Date
     , B.Year as Base_Date1
     , A.comment as Base_Date_Comment
     , B.Comment as Base_Date1_Comment
FROM CTE A
LEFT JOIN CTE  B
  on A.RN+1 = B.RN
 and A.Company = B.Company
 and B.RN = 2
WHERE A.RN = 1
```

Note the limit on RN=2 must be on the join since it's an outer join or we would eliminate the companies without 2 years. (in essence making the left join an inner)

This approach makes all columns of the data available for each row.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `self join` to do this. However, you should think about dates like February 29 as they only occur in leap years.

```
select t1.company,t1.year as basedate,t2.year as basedate_1,
t1.comment as comment_basedate,t2.comment as comment_basedate_1
from t t1
left join t t2 on t1.company=t2.company dateadd(year,1,t2.year)=t1.year
```

Change the `left join` to an `inner join` if you only need results where both the date values exist for a company. This solution assumes there can only be one comment per day.

Comment: You should only need company and year in the join, based on his example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! It indeed makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two rows each, then that's pretty simple.  If there are more than two rows, you could do something like this  -- essentially joining all rows, then making sure A represents the earliest row and B represents the latest row.

```
SELECT A.Company, A.Year AS [Base Date], B.Year  AS [Base Date 1],
       A.Comment AS [Comment Base Date], B.Comment AS [Comment Base Date 1]
FROM MyTable A
    INNER JOIN MyTable B ON A.Company = B.Company
WHERE A.Year = (SELECT MIN(C.YEAR) FROM MyTable C WHERE C.Company = A.Company)
  AND B.Year = (SELECT MAX(C.YEAR) FROM MyTable C WHERE C.Company = B.Company)
```

There might be a more efficient way to do this with Row_Number or something.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!